# Fast 'Find in Files' for VIM?

Tags: search, vim, full-text-search, find, code-search-engine

What are some options for getting really fast 'Find in Files' searching in VIM?

Our codebase is large enough that searching needs to work off an index. grep/vimgrep/etc are too slow.

Indexing doesn't need to be particularly fast; I can index overnight.

Thanks,

[EDIT] I'm also working in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's source code (rather than full text search), then ctags with the TagList plugin should work well for your needs.  See, for example:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/

EDIT: TagList and ctags will work on Windows as well (that's what I use).  See the TagList install page and FAQ.  The following links might prove useful:

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273
- http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/installation.html
- http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/faq.html

There's also a TagList forum where you can get further help:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/taglist/

I set it up on my windows machine a while back, but I don't remember encountering any problems.

Answer (score 5):

Something that I use, but not through vim, is ack: http://betterthangrep.com/

It is a perl based tool, and it should be usable in Windows.

Comment: This works very well for me. We have thousands of files, and a normal grep (or even ack) can take tens of seconds. But something like `:Ack --ruby *something*` will generally return in a second or two, since it is searching only a subset of files

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with a large codebase, then it might be time to look for a more powerful solution than conventional tools. [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) is a very fast source code search and cross-reference engine. On top of its great performance, it integrates with [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/), and [ClearCase](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/products/clearcase/), among other source revision control software. It sounds a lot like something you could use.

If you want support to use OpenGrok from within Vim, you could easily write a vim function that would call `system()` to start the search for you. To read more about writing new vim commands, look up [`:help 40.2`](http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.2) within vim.

I hope that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how I found this, but looks like someone has written a plugin for [google desktop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2311)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim, http://beyondgrep.com/ ,

then make a link

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ack-grep /usr/bin/ack
```

and add

```
noremap <C-f> :copen<CR>:Ack -aQi --ignore-dir someignoringdir
```

to your .vimrc, after you can find in files through Ctrl+F, enjoy

```
_   /|
\'o.O'
=(___)=
   U
```

Comment: Not sure if this will be faster than builtin grep or vimgrep.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

> :vimgrep /something/ **/*

and dont forget to open search result window after

> :cw