# Open all files that match a certain pattern in Vim

Tags: vim, grep

I’m in `~/src`. I can do `git grep _pattern_` and get a list of all `*.cpp` or `*.hpp` files that match this *pattern*.

Now I would like to go through all the files that match the *pattern* and make edits on them. How do I do this in Vim? (Basically, I want Vim to go through my directory like git grep does, and jump me to the right files.)

Comment: Seems redundant with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716470/can-you-mass-edit-all-files-returned-in-a-grep and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095314/fast-find-in-files-for-vim

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468763/how-do-i-make-vim-open-all-files-matching-a-pattern-in-different-tabs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the single inverted commas (also a unix shell feature), something like:

```
vim `git grep --name-only <your expression>`
```

Comment: Most people call them backticks ;)

Comment: Agreed, it’s really a grave misuse of terminology.

Comment: You should favour the `$(command)` syntax over the backtick `\`command\`` syntax.  The former is clearer and nest'able, while the later gets confusing when quotes and apostrophes are involved and cannot be nested.

Answer (score 10):

In bash, you could do

```
vim $(grep -l _pattern_ *.cpp *.hpp)
```

but that's a bash feature, not a vim feature.

Answer (score 6):

you can use the args ex command:

```
:args *.cpp *.hpp
```

This will open all cpp and hpp files in the current directory.

You can use any file path expansions available to :grep as well.

Answer (score 3):

By properly using the quickfix list, you can even go immediately to the the right line (using the `:help quickfix` commands, eg. `:cn` or `:cw`). So, if you are using bash or zsh:

```
vim -q <(git grep foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could possibly set the grepprg and grepformat options to run `git grep...` and interpret the result.  This would then let you run the command :grep and read the results into the quickfix buffer - see `:h quickfix` for more information.  You can then step through them with :cnext and :cprev, or :copen to open a separate window with the list of files - putting the cursor on a filename and pressing return will open that file for editing.

The advantage of this over Zoran's and ammoQ's suggestions is that it will not read the files into memory until you want to edit them.  Their suggestion will load possibly hundreds of files into memory at once, and can be a nightmare to manage.  It is also cross platform so should work on Windows without having to use a third-party shell such as cygwin bash.