# How do I make vim open all files matching a pattern in different tabs?

Tags: vim, vi

In a given working directory, if I do

```
:tabe **/test*.py
```

`vim` complains with `E77: Too many file names`. What if I want it to open every matching file in a separate tab? There must be a way to do it, but I can't find it.

Comment: Related: [How can I open multiple tabs at once?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2108/how-can-i-open-multiple-tabs-at-once) at Vim SE

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use the `args` list and `argdo` like so:

```
:args **/test*.py
:argdo tabe %
```

However, the syntax event is turned off by `argdo` (to speed up the normal use case), so the files will be loaded without syntax at first.  You could follow it up with a `:syntax on` to force the syntax event on all loaded buffers.  Compressed into one line (need to wrap `argdo` in `execute` so it doesn't absorb the following `|`):

```
:args **/test*.py | execute 'argdo tabe %' | syntax on
```

Alternately, you can open vim from the command line via:

```
vim -p **/test*.py
```

But that will max out at 10 tabs.

Comment: thanks a lot!
now, how could I make the pattern a parameter so I can map the script to a new command and I can do, e.g. `:tabeall **/test*.py`?

Comment: `set tabpagemax=100` will allow vim to open 100 tabs.

Comment: As said below, the answer by @cooldoger is much quicker, shorter and easier. I guess that problem here is the good old vim confusion between "tabs" and "bufffers" (cf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs#26710166) . I don't think it's useful to open 100 tabs, better to use buffers instead, and learn how to use them right (cf here for example:https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following:

```
:next **/test*.py
```

It opens all the files.

Comment: how is this not the correct answer? it's much simper !

Comment: I agree that this answer is much better, simpler and faster, but as the question ask for "different tabs" I guess that the accepted answer is the good one.

Comment: I don't see how this does what was asked. If I try it, just one buffer opens.

Answer (score 1):

To map it

```
nmap <c-d> :args **/*.tpl<bar>execute 'argdo tabe %'<bar>syntax on<cr>
```

But still it displays list of files, you have to press enter few times (depending of number of files).

Comment: Or `nmap <c-d> :args **/*.tpl ^M argdo tabe % ^M syntax on ^M`
Use Control-Q to type the ^M (literal newline) character. Still displays the list of files, though.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality can be included as a command in your `.vimrc` file:

```
"open all files in seperate tabs
command -nargs=1 OpenAll call <SID>openAll(<f-args>)
function! s:openAll(dir)
    execute 'args ' . a:dir
    silent argdo tabe %
    syntax on
endfunction
```

With this function running `:OpenAll **/*.py` from vim will quickly open all files into new tabs

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers works for me, but this is fine:

```
find <path> -iname <pattrn> | xargs -o vim -p
```

- all files are visible in different tabs
- file lookup is recursive

Note, vim can limit tabs - to be changed by `set tabpagemax=42`.

Also, if you wonder how to close all tabs at once, use `:qa`